# jquery .not() usage to exclude spedified selector by parent id

Tags: jquery

A given script selects two elements, but I want to exclude one specific which is defined by  it's parent ID: '#submenu li#livezilla a'

I tried this:

```
$("#hauptmenu li a, #submenu li a").not("#submenu li#livezilla a").bind("mouseover", function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
```

but something wrong (no knowledge of jquery or JS on my side - - -)

Comment: You have to include the javascript error on your question. Is that the whole line with the error?

Answer (score 3):

The selectors work just fine. I tested it, and it selects all the links it should:

http://jsfiddle.net/RMdjd/

So, there is either something wrong with your HTML code, or what you are trying to do doesn't work.

It sure does have some effect, but it might actually be the opposite of the intended. The event seem only bubble from the one element that doesn't have the event handler. Pointing on `li` elements will change their background color, but pointing on the `a` elements doesn't cause the `li` element to change background color, except for the one `a` element that does't have the `mouseover` event handler:

http://jsfiddle.net/RMdjd/1/

Comment: wow! what a fast and thorough reply, thanks!
The thing is more complicated; I have a script, jquery.menumator.js, which affects another script, LiveZilla Live Chat.
http://wishbone-design.de/flexible-layouts.htm

I just found out - it works if the URL with www is used! The CMS is modX.
so it's not related to this selector!